# Firebase functions 1.0 event.params.pushId, event.data.ref

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

can't find `event.params.pushId` and `event.data.ref` in documentation

Comment: did you check the answer?

Comment: yes, but I have ran into other incompatibilities

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined`

Comment: did you write it as the answer below? Are you sure you are using firebase function 1.0?

Comment: problem was `.onCreate` does not have `after`

Comment: yes Im using onWrite in the example below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.params.pushId` and `event.data.ref` were changed into this:

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path/with/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
const wildcards=context.params.pushId;
const data=change.after.ref;

});
```

> For onWrite and onUpdate events, the data parameter has `before` and `after` fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot` with the same methods available here:
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot

`ref` is one of the properties of `DataSnapshot`, thus you are able to access it as above.

Check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database